# How can i reserve an wp7 app name in wp7 market place?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

It is possible to "register" an windows phone7 App Name before the app goes on the app store or market palce?

For example i want register the name before my application completion so  that no one else comes up with the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. Duplicate names are allowed on the Windows Phone marketplace anyway, so reserving a name wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @user1774180 That duplicates are allowed? Unfortunately, yes: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/tile-it/36d2184a-c2f1-df11-9264-00237de2db9e, http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/tile-it/da1536ef-d350-e011-854c-00237de2db9e